# Up to which extent do configuration issues belong on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I'm sure this question has been asked here several times, however I failed to find the correct search terms.

Lately I've seen a lot of questions which are more configuration than programming related problems on SO. Most of them are PHP beginners, but that's probably because I mainly look at PHP questions.

Example? Those four questions have been posted more or less within an hour:

- [How do I enable mbstring extension on PHP 5, Fedora server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796841/how-do-i-enable-mbstring-extension-on-php-5-fedora-server)
- [XDebug installed but not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796620/xdebug-installed-but-not-working)
- [Mail sent “on behalf of” when using PHP Pear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797063/mail-sent-on-behalf-of-when-using-php-pear)
- [Cannot use ndk-build on Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797509/cannot-use-ndk-build-on-cygwin)

In my opinion the first two are clearly configuration rather than programming problems. The third one is a border line case. And number four probably never used a shell in his life before.. (However I'm not proficient enough on his subject to be sure about this.)

The SO FAQ states that questions concerning `software tools commonly used by programmers` are welcome on SO. Does that mean that the above questions are at the right place? (If so I'm sorry having wasted your time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always the votes to migrate.

All those questions cited by you are asked by "youngsters" probably not familiar with the FAQs and should have been voted to be migrated to serverfault or other according SE sites.

I, at least have used my remaining last 4 votes for today to suggest moving them to serverfault.